# Adding new objects to a dictionary while iterating through a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I've been trying to add objects with specific properties to a `Dictionary<int, DwgObject>` dictionary in a while loop by reading through values in anexcel column.
It seems even though I'm declaring a new object in my loop, the properties of my respective objects end up being the same throughout the dictionary.
Here's the while loop I'm using:

```
Dictionary<int, DrawingObj> lst = new Dictionary<int, DrawingObj>(); 
int numRows = 0;

//Loop through Drawing Number column -> Add new obj to list with drawing number prop
//Iterate to next row down -> check for empty string to break loop 
string current = wks.Cells[row, column]?.Value2?.ToString() ?? "";
while ((current != ""))
 {
     DrawingObj newDWG = new DrawingObj();
     newDWG.dwgNumber = current; 
     lst.Add(numRows, newDWG);
     numRows++;
     current = wks.Cells[(row + numRows), column].Text;
  }
```

The resulting dictionary gives me 13 entries of objects with the property dwgNumber equal to the string of my last excel value. How can I store the unique property values for key-value pair?

Update: I tried changing the loop to pull out the properties of each object as a single string and storing to an array, then later on, using a loop to create an object instance with all of the properties at once. But this results in the same error. See below:

```
//store string of all properties with delimiter '|'
while ((current != ""))
{
    StringBuilder properties = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
       properties.Append(wks.Cells[(row + numRows), propColIndex[i]].Text);
       if(i != propColIndex.Length - 1) { properties.Append("|"); }
    }
    propStrings.Add(properties.ToString());
    numRows++;
    current = wks.Cells[(row + numRows), column].Text;
}

//for each property string create new object w/ props -> add object to dictionary foreach (var props in propStrings) // t i = 1; i <= numRows-1; i++)
{
    percent = (j / numRows) * 60;
    int k = 0;
    string[] values = new string[8];

    foreach (string prop in props.Split(delimiter))
    {
       values[k] = prop;
       k++;
    }
    DrawingObj newDWG = new DrawingObj()
    {
                    dwgNumber = values[0],
                    sheetNo = values[1],
                    revNo = values[2],
                    keyWord = values[3],
                    dwgType = values[4],
                    descSublocation = values[5],
                    revType = values[6],
                    fileName=values[7],
                    facilityLoc = constFacilFields[0],
                    facilityType = constFacilFields[1],
                    jobOrderNum = constFacilFields[2]
     };
     lst.Add(j-1, newDWG);
     j++;
```

Comment: Your issue is that `string` is a reference type, so you actually have 13 instances of `DrawingObj`, but they're all pointing to the same string (`current`).

Comment: Ah I see. Would making a new string instance in my loop referencing current every iteration solve this or would it still have the same outcome?

Comment: @HansKilian They're only pointing to the same string if the worksheet's cell's text is the same string reference for each of the objects.  It would behave no differently if it were a value type, given that the value is never mutating.

Comment: Try not using current and assigning the cell contents directly. Something like `newDWG.dwgNumber = wks.Cells[(row + numRows), column].Text;`

Comment: @HansKilian I tried that and got the same result

Comment: I've tried reproducing your problem and I can't. Your code works for me. How do you determine that the 13 instances you get have the same `dwgNumber`?

Comment: use your debugger to step through the code and examine the values of the relevant variables on each iteration.

Comment: @HansKilian I have a watch on lst[0] and lst[1], and set a breakpoint to look at each loop. The first iteration properly stores the property values for lst[0], but as I continue, every loop adds a new object entry and also changes the properties of every individual entry to what is being added in that instance of the loop.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark given the age of this post, but did you happen to solve this issue, @Cedryc? I’ve got a very similar problem and it’s doing my head in.